# Is capturing a `const Whatever &` into an asynchronous lambda unsafe?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda

I have some asynchronous code that uses a lambda, which I suspect is buggy.  An example of the problem is here (note: pseudo-code, but the real code is based on JUCE's Threading API) :

```
// SUSPECT CODE (?)
void MessageReceived(const Message & msgRef) {
    Threading(this).runAsync([&, msgRef] {
        msgRef.Print();  // or whatever
    });
}
```

In particular, I believe that it is unsafe to use `msgRef` from inside the lambda-body, because while the lambda mechanism made a copy of the `const Message &`, the actual `Message` object that the reference was referring to was *not* copied, and therefore `msgRef` is very likely to be a dangling-reference by the time the asynchronous lambda-callback routine actually executes.

My question is, is my reasoning above correct?  If not, what am I missing?

Also, is the following code sufficient to avoid the problem?  In this case my function makes a local copy (`localCopy`) of the `Message` object, and the lambda-callback references that instead.  I believe the lambda-capture mechanism will make its own private copy of `localCopy` that is guaranteed to be valid when the asynchronous routine accesses it.

```
// FIXED CODE (?)
void MessageReceived(const Message & msgRef) {
    Message localCopy = msgRef;
    Threading(this).runAsync([&, localCopy] {
       localCopy.Print();  // or whatever
    });
}
```

Comment: In the first version, I don't see how there's enough information about the lifespan of whatever `msgRef` refers to know whether a dangling reference is or is not likely. The second version looks like it's guaranteed to cause a dangling reference unless `MessageReceived` doesn't return until the `runAsync` call has finished, which seems like it would defeat the purpose of invoking it asynchronously.

Comment: By-value capturing a reference copies the reference target, not the reference itself.

Comment: @NathanPierson assume that `msgRef` refers to a local variable of the function that is calling `MessageReceived()`, and so will be destroyed shortly after `MessageReceived()` returns (and likely before the lambda-routine executes)

Comment: Sure. But then I don't see how your proposed code does anything different. `localCopy` is a local variable of the function `MessageReceived`. If you think the lambda is going to be executing after `MessageReceived` has returned, you haven't solved anything.

Comment: @NathanPierson I was under the (mis)impression that an independent copy of `localCopy` would be made for the lambda to use.   So the only effective fix is to replace `runAsync([&, ...]` with `runAsync([=, ...]` ?

Comment: Capturing a reference by-copy means that the closure type will contain a member of the _referenced_ type which is initialized from the captured reference. `msgRef` in the lambda is not the object that `msgRef` outside of it refers to but a copy of it. Same with `localCopy`. That way you have three objects: The one referenced by `msgRef` outside the lambda, the `localCopy` copy and a copy inside the lambda.

Comment: @user17732522 just to make sure I'm following you, by "capturing a reference by-copy" you are referring to doing a `runAsync([=, msgRef])`, correct?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner No, `msgRef` is an explicit by-copy capture, overriding the capture default `=`/`&` for that entity. `&msgRef` would be by-reference.

Comment: The default capture `&` in both examples has no effect and can be ommitted.

Comment: BTW, above mentioned `runAsync([=, msgRef])` is ill-formed according to the standard. "If a lambda-capture includes a capture-default that is =, each simple-capture of that
lambda-capture shall be of the form “& identifier” or “* this”." Your `[&, localVarByCopy]` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first short example is correct. After the default capture by reference you explicitly capture your `msgRef` by copy - that is lambda holds the copy of the referenced object.

**[expr.prim.lambda.capture]**

> An entity is captured by copy if
>
> (10.2) — it is explicitly captured with a capture that is not of the form this, & identifier, or & identifier
> initializer.
>
> (...)
>
> The type of such a data member **is the referenced type** if the entity is a reference to an object, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise.

And later on the standard gives this example:

```
[&, i]{ }; // OK
```

This is assuming that in your `MessageReceived` body you don't have any automatic variables that will be captured by default `&` and then accidentally misused in the lambda body.